# MS Projects - Macro that grabs certain tasks from subprojects into master

Tags: vba, ms-project, subproject

I am looking to build a Macro in MS Projects and am trying to hash it out conceptually first. Any help would be great.

I ultimately want a master project to show each sub project by means of each section.

I currently have 3 devices that each have 3 sections, and they all have the same 3 sections but different tasks in each.

Each section is basically a nested task schedule specific to that device.

For instance:
Green Device
Section 1: Acquisition  (nested task schedule for green device)
Section 2: Contracts
Section 3: Logistics

Blue Device
Section 1: Acquisition
Section 2: Contracts
Section 3: Logistics

Red Device
Section 1: Acquisition
Section 2: Contracts
Section 3: Logistics

Again, each device has the same sections, but have different schedules from eachother.

I want the master to show:

Master Schedule
Section 1: Acquisition
Green Device: Acquisition part only
Blue Device: Acquisition part only
Red Device: Acquisition part only

Section 2: Contracts
Green Device: Contracts part only
Blue Device: Contracts part only
Red Device: Contracts part only

Section 3: Logistics
Green Device: Logistics part only
Blue Device: Logistics part only
Red Device: Logistics part only

//

I am looking for the Master Project to be generated by the macro and be "static" and not linked to the sub-projects. I would like each engineer of each device to control their respective device's project schedule. And when I want to see them all together, I want to generate the master schedule by running the macro. I dont want the master schedule to change the sub projects at all, essentially not dynamic.

Any thoughts?

I am sorry to say that I am not experienced with VBA, however, I am trying to set up the conceptual pseudo code type of language for clear communication.

Basically, I am wanting to stich subprojects together by means of their respective sections.

Comment: This would be a sizable macro. As you do not know VBA is someone on your team going to write it? Stack overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: When copying only a section of a schedule to a new schedule, you will need to hard-code all dates with constraints such as Must Finish On. Better to include the entire schedule and use Grouping, Sorting and/or Filtering to show the tasks in the order you want.

Comment: The best answer is probably to import the three schedules into a blank one and then use grouping. This can be done with a few manual steps.

Comment: Understood, and I didn’t realize that the dates and such would need to be hard coded. It does sound like grouping will make the most sense. I can import all of the projects like you had said and then group certain parts of each project together. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Andrew, a macro to do what you want isn't all that complex. If you want to automate the process I suggest you record a macro of going through the steps to combine all projects into a static master and then applying grouping as Rachel suggested. As long as the projects always have the same path, all you need to do for an update is to run your recorded macro.